# How do you turn off the croak sound for Toad?

Tags: configuration, toad

How do you turn off this annoying feature? I don't want my DB manager to croak at me as loud as it can.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Issue:** You are experiencing a noise / croak sound when TOAD starts up.

**Solution:** http://www.odipundits.com/2017/01/how-to-get-rid-of-croak-sound-at-toad.html

1. `View` in the top toolbar -> `Toad Options` from the list.
2. Click on `Startup` in the left pane after scrolling down a ways.
3. Uncheck the box `Play Toad wave file` and then click `ok`. Click `apply` instead if you wish to continue navigating through the pane.

The next time it starts up, it should not play that sound.

Comment: This worked on v16.1

Answer (score 0):

For **Toad Data Point 5.4**, I went to `Tools > Options > Environment > General`.

From there, you can disable:

- **Play toad sound on startup**
- **Background Process Notifications** > **Play toad sound when finished**

[image: toad data point 5.4 croak sound settings]